# Cannot update UILabel text after dismissing UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am presenting a UIViewController over the other one. When I dismiss the presented UIViewController and return back to the current one and try to update UILabel text, it is not updated. I don't know why. Below, `customTimeViewController` is my presented UIViewController. When a button is clicked on it, my below function is called by the delegate. I try to update my UILabel (`targetTimeText`) text, but it is not updated.

I tried `layoutIfNeeded()`, `setNeedsLayout()`, and `setNeedsDisplay()`. Nothing helped.

```
func selectedCustomTime(minutes: Int, seconds: Int) {
    customTimeViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.targetTimeText.text = GameTimeUtility.convertTimeToHumanReadable(time: minutes*60+seconds)
}
```

Comment: I recommend you to use Protocol when sending a value to previous page.

Comment: Question is not clear that lead to misunderstanding the idea of the error! next time should be more careful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Notification protocol or Delegate protocol in this situation. Try this code that using protocol and change the variable or function name to your current code.

```
protocol MydataDelegate{
    func passingData(mystring: String)
}

Class SecondViewController: UIViewController{

    var mdataDelegate: MydataDelegate!

    func selectedCustomTime(minutes: Int, seconds: Int) {
        mdataDelegate.passingData(mystring: GameTimeUtility.convertTimeToHumanReadable(time: minutes*60+seconds))
        customTimeViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

Class FirstViewController: UIViewController,MydataDelegate{

    func openSecondVC(){

        // Mark: Try your code that open new viewcontroller but don't forget pass your delegate
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        let vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
        vc.mdataDelegate = self
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func passingData(mystring: String){
        self.targetTimeText.text = mystring
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i am already using delegate to transfer data between ViewControllers

Comment: Oh! I See, So how about Notification protocol? have you tried it yet? but still, maybe your code is invalid somewhere because delegate protocol always works for me! If you still can't solve that yet, you can post your code that you currently do though

Answer (score -1):

I solved it guys,

I was adding my UILabel (targetTimeText) in the code by calling addSubview() method.After adding it if i call setNeedsLayout(), then everything worked. Please check below

```
self.view.addSubview(targetTimeText)
view.setNeedsLayout()
```